# Road to holomorphic foliations?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, foliations, learning-roadmap

I want to know a "knowledge road" to holomorphic foliations. I assume that differential geometry and complex analysis is needed, but, what else? For example, I want to be able to read Lins Neto's book "Folheacoes algebricas complexas".

Comment: Add some algebraic geometry to your list.